# Link all DLLs in a folder with Premake5

Tags: c#, lua, premake

I'm moving some Unity code into a VS2022 project to use a plugin. Since this code references many different Unity classes I need to link in the Unity's DLLs in my Unity install. This is all fine and dandy, but I wanted to generate the project with Premake5.

I've been searching around and while I can link specific DLLs in the folder by setting `libdirs "my unity DLLs"` followed by a `link "UnityEditor.dll"` it seems like `link` might not support wildcards in the way `files` does. Is there a way to instruct Premake5 to grab all the dlls without manually listing all of them (there are many) that I'm not aware of? I'd also be fine with a lua workaround to grab the file names from the folder as long as it's reasonably portable.

Here is my premake.lua for reference grabbing only the single UnityEditor.dll

```
local ROOT   = "../"
local SOURCE = ROOT.."Source/"
local BUILD  = ROOT.."Build/"

workspace "RELoad_CorePlugin"
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
    location (ROOT)
    dotnetframework "net6.0"

project "RELoad_Core"
    kind "SharedLib"
    language "C#"
    libdirs "C:/Program Files/Unity/2021.3.12f1/Editor/Data/Managed/UnityEngine/" -- hard coded for now
    links "UnityEditor.dll" 

    targetdir (ROOT.."Output")
    location (BUILD)
    files (SOURCE.."Core/**.cs")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want [`os.matchfiles`](https://premake.github.io/docs/os.matchfiles)

```
local dll_pattern = "C:/Program Files/Unity/2021.3.12f1/Editor/Data/Managed/UnityEngine/*.dll"
local fullpath_dlls = os.matchfiles(dll_pattern)
local dlls = table.translate(fullpath_dlls, path.getname)

links(dlls)
```

Comment: I gave this a go, and fullpath_dlls is empty, even if I hardcode it to a specific file that I know exists. I also tried hardcoding a relative path with the same result. Is there something I'm missing here? For the record, C++ is more my wheelhouse, so it's possible there's some basic lua thing I've not realized I need to do here.

Comment: Woops disregard my previous comment, I just realized there was a typo in my path to the unity files (missing the 'd' in 'managed'). After correcting that your solution worked, and is way better than my workaround as it's not platform specific. Thanks!